# Writing to event log by using data from config file

Tags: c#, trace, event-log

I am doing some practice tests for Microsoft's "Programming in C#" exam 70-483 and one of the questions has me in a stump and I don't know enough about tracing to test it properly.

The question is this:

You are developing an application that uses a .config file.

The relevant portion of the .config file is shown as follows:

```
   <system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="0">
         <listeners>
            <add name="appListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"
               initializeData="TraceListenerLog" />
         </listeners>
      </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
```

You need to ensure that diagnostic data for the application writes to the event log by using the configuration specified in the .config file.
What should you include in the application code?

A. `EventLog log = new EventLog();
<br/>log.WriteEntry("Trace data...");`

B. `Debug.WriteLine("Trace data...");`

C. `Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter("System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener")); <br/>Console.WriteLine("Trace data...");`

D. `Trace.WriteLine("Trace data...");`

I'm thinking "C" because it's the only option that has *something* to do with the .config file, but it says the correct answer is "D" for some reason. Mind you these questions have been wrong before about completely simple and obvious stuff, so...

Can you please explain which is the correct answer and why?

Comment: C is the absolute worst - not only does it have *nothing* to do with System.Diagnostics or the EventLog, it will try to create a file named `System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, whoopsie! :)

Comment: You can't just brute force a certification exam. They are *designed* to trick you up. In fact, that's why experienced developers hate them. If you read the tracing documentation or the tracing section in the online courses/books you'll quickly realize that A and C don't apply at all

Comment: For example, in *this* question both B and D work, in different builds. Does the question text ask for tracing only in debug builds or all the time? I suspect it means "all the time" but doesn't make it explicit

Comment: There are far worse questions where the correct option may differ only in a comma.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, just thought I'd let you know I just brute forced the exam. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *solution* is to [read about tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-create-and-initialize-trace-sources) instead of trying to just find the correct answer.

`C` is the absolute worst - not only does it have *nothing* to do with System.Diagnostics or the EventLog, it will try to create a file named `System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener`.

The only options that actually use `System.Diagnostics` are B and D.

The `<system.diagnostics><trace>` section in app.config *configures* the System.Diagnostics classes, including sources, listeners, switches that activate or deactive specific sources in the application etc. It's no different really than the configuration files used for any other log library like log4net, Serilog or NLog.

- `Debug.WriteLine("Trace data...");` will write the output to all the configured trace listeners, only in a debug build.
- `Trace.WriteLine("Trace data...");` will write to all configured trace listeners both in debug and release builds.

Option `A` is wrong too. It does involve the event log, but won't work because the Source isn't set. [EventLog.WriteEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.writeentry?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_EventLog_WriteEntry_System_String_) doesn't send any *diagnostic* information either, it just writes an Information message to the Event Log.

The System.Diagnostics listener on the other hand will receive diagnostic events from the *myriad* of trace sources in .NET, including the application's own, filter it, and write it to its target.

Do you have a problem with networking for example? You can switch the System.Net trace listeners on and collect trace messages from the HTTP level all the way down to sockets, SSL, TCP and even packet operations.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the "D", What that configuration file is doing.. is adding an instance to the trace.Listeners. So whenever you call Trace.WriteLine one of the outputs will be to that listener you set up in the config file.

"C" would work too, but it does say that you need to ensure that you use the config file, and what you are doing in C has nothing to do with the config file.

Comment: C is unrelated. The question asks how to use the Diagnostigs mechanism to write trace output to the event log. C has nothing to do with either System.Diagnostics or the event log